# Unable to run the main method

Tags: scala, sbt

I am currently working on a system where staff members in an organization can be informed regarding their pending tasks to be completed by their managers via devices. This is demonstrated via the following classes:

1. Staff
2. Manager (Extends Staff)
3. Device (Receives tasks and removes them once completed)
4. Task
5. System (Assigns tasks)
6. Main

I am currently stuck at a point where I am unable to determine why I cannot run my classes, as I receive a non-zero exit code of 1.

The problem currently seems to lie within the Main.scala file, at the moment:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var system = new System

    var s1 = new Staff(1, "John", "johndoe@outlook.com", "Brazil")
    system.addStaff(s1)
    var s2 = new Manager(2, "Reese", "reesecups@gmail.com", "Japan")
    system.addStaff(s2)

    s2.assignTask(system, 1, "PLEASE WORK")

  }

}
```

The code used to run as intended, however when I added the following line to the Main.scala file:
`s2.assignTask(system, 1, "PLEASE WORK")`

I received the following error:

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$4(Defaults.scala:1477)
[error]         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$3(Defaults.scala:1477)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
```

Is there any indication to what the problem may be?

Comment: I've added this line [mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.Main")] into my build.sbt, and it seems to create the same error, on top of a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Main.scala is a file, do I need to change my declaration from object to class?

Comment: They weren't valid commands? Did you use it in the following way? `runMain com.Main`

Comment: I used it wrongly. Once I fixed the syntax, I still got the same error log as above.

Comment: How are you trying to run this?

Comment: Which version sbt do you use? Instead of `(Compile, run) := Some("com.Main")` it could have been `Compile / run := ...` for  a while, except that would override the whole run command, not the main class. For that is should be `mainClass := Some("com.Main")`.

Comment: @mfirry I am running this only via the run command in sbt. I've been unable to pinpoint the exact cause of my issues

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I am using version 1.3.9.

Comment: What's the package of the Main object?

Comment: it's com, and I've specified it as such (mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.Main")). I don't think it's an issue with the declaration, more so it might be my source code.

Comment: Does `Main` file have `package com` at the top or is it just in `com` directory within`src/main/scala`?